# Which is correct: "The board of X" or "The board for X"?

Tags: prepositions

If I want to name a board in an organisation, do I use *of* or *for*? For instance, do I say "The board **of** teacher education" or "The board **for** teacher education"? If I can use either, with a difference in meaning, what is the difference?

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect that depends hugely on what comes next. It is always _board of directors_ for instance. Having said that have you considered a construction like _the teacher education board_ which gets round the problem?

Comment: @mdewey Haha – no, for some reason I never thought of that! But yes – that's an excellent solution! Thank you so much!! As for choice of preposition, I'm thinking that perhaps it depends on whether we want to say what the board consists of or are part of (in which case we use "of"), or what the board is concerned with (in which case we use "for")?